# MySQL: Before Update trigger is also firing on insert, why?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables, A, B and C where A is the parent of B, B is A's child. C is the history of B.

Below is a diagram showing the relationships and multiplicity (note both relationships are identifying).

```
0..*      1
B ------- A 
| 1 
| 
| 0..* 
C
```

The insert statement for B is of the form

```
insert into B ... on duplicate key update ...
```

There is a trigger in B such that before an update it copies the current row on B to C i.e. C  contains the history of B.

The above works great when there is no A. When the A relationship is added I find that the trigger is fired twice, both on insert into B and update on B - why?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**
@Randy: here is the simplified trigger code:

```
USE `blah`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `B_BUPD` BEFORE UPDATE ON `B` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO C ( ... some values ... )
    VALUES ( now(), ... some old. values ... );
END
```

**Update:**
@ron tornambe: here is the cut down SQL for the tables. I've had to removed the sensitive information and other tables that appear not to effect this problem, but hopefully it still makes sense / is useful.

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `blah` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `blah` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `blah`.`A`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blah`.`A` (

  ...

  PRIMARY KEY (`mac_address`, `sensor_mac_address`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_detector_sensor`
    FOREIGN KEY (`sensor_mac_address`)
    REFERENCES `blah`.`X` (`mac_address`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `blah`.`B`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blah`.`B` (

  ...

  PRIMARY KEY (`mac_address`),
  INDEX `fk_device_detector1_idx` (`detector_mac_address` ASC, `sensor_mac_address` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_device_detector1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`detector_mac_address` , `sensor_mac_address`)
    REFERENCES `blah`.`A` (`mac_address` , `sensor_mac_address`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `blah`.`C`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blah`.`C` (

  ...

  PRIMARY KEY (`time_date`, `mac_address`, `detector_mac_address`, `sensor_mac_address`),
  INDEX `fk_history_device1_idx` (`mac_address` ASC, `detector_mac_address` ASC, `sensor_mac_address` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_history_device1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`mac_address` , `detector_mac_address` , `sensor_mac_address`)
    REFERENCES `blah`.`device` (`mac_address` , `detector_mac_address` , `sensor_mac_address`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `B_BUPD` BEFORE UPDATE ON `B` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO C ( ... some values ... )
    VALUES ( now(), ... some old. values ... );
END$$
```

Comment: post the trigger code - especially the part that says CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER .. ON INSERT OR UPDATE..

Comment: @Randy: simplified trigger code added.

Comment: oops, some typos (sorry). now corrected

Comment: Is this happening when your are inserting a duplicate key? Also, please ost the table definition (or make an sqlfiddle) so we. can see the foreign keys

Comment: @ron tornambe: The trigger occurs when I add the first record (an insert), and then twice for each update (I assume one per update and one for the incorrect insert). Here is the cut down SQL for the tables.

Comment: It looks as though table blah.A references itself?

Comment: Not that there is anything wrong with that. Are you certain there aren't any other triggers that may insert into C?

Comment: Darn, my mistake. When editing the SQL - A should not reference itself ( I have fixed this now). And no, there is only one trigger.
I will produce a reduced version of the problem and post the full SQL.